# Textbox disables on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox and dropdown with items `All, abc, etc`. i wanted javascript code that disables the textbox when all is selected and enable it when anything else is selected. 

 I worked it out with that code but the issue is that if form is posted the textbox is disabled even when abc or anything else is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeddl() {
        document.getElementById("txtsearch").disabled = document.getElementById("ddlcolumn").value == "All";
    }
</script>
```

aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcolumn" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" Width="120px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="Search" onchange="changeddl();" >
    <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>abc</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="200px"
     ValidationGroup="Search" ClientIDMode="Static" SkinID="txt"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `changeddl()` function on  `body onload`

```
<body onload="changeddl()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;


if(e === "All"){
     document.getElementById("txtsearch").style.display = "none"; // However you want to 'disable'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On postback of your page, write the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(ddlcolumn.SelectedValue == "All")
     {
          txtsearch.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
     }
     else
     {
          txtsearch.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
     }
}
```